# Size of Enumeration<String>

Tags: java

How can I get the size of an `Enumeration<String>` without iterate over it?

While debugging I can see the `size` of the the enumeration but I can't find a way to get this value.

Comment: You can't. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html. BTW, the enumeration could very well be infinite.

Comment: Note that if you're using an Enumeration, thee is a chance you're doing something wrong. This interface is effectively deprecated. It has been replaced long ago, in Java 1.2, by Iterator.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to retrieve headers from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, there is another way to retrieve them without using enumeration?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can at least be sure that this one is not infinite, and transform the enumeration to a list using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list-java.util.Enumeration-

Comment: I prefer not transforming to list due to complexity, so I guess I must use deprecated Enumeration. Thank you

Comment: If a list of headers is complex, what is not? But of course, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) interface does not expose its size, and some (many?) implementations indeed do not have this knowledge. Without any knowledge of the specific implementation, you have no choice but to iterate over it.

Answer (score 8):

You can do `Collections.list(enumerationObject).size();` to get the number of elements.

Comment: This creates a list. The list is created by iterating through every entry...

Comment: (up-voting) since size is not exposed as a field or get method, there is no option but counting, which this does and looks fine. Will be glad to see a more-optimized way.

Comment: FWIW, and for future me, in case you want to avoid iterating over the enumeration, and you just want to determine if it is empty or not, you can call `enumerationObject.hasMoreElements()`.